# Does it make sense to use Stocks for currency transfer?

Tags: stocks, currency, international-transfer

Does it make sense to think of buying a stable/safe stock in money held in country A (in currency A), then selling it in country B (in currency B) to get a better money conversion rate ?

Can ignore the volatility of the stock for simplicity.

Comment: Why do you think you'd get a better conversion rate? You'd likely be crossing the bid/ask spread of the stock _and_ the currency conversion.

Comment: Refer to "Norbert's Gambit" for CAD/USD conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losing Money with Norbert's Gambit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84838/losing-money-with-norberts-gambit)

Comment: Note that whether the above linked answer applies to you would depend on which currencies you are talking about, and most specifically, whether those currencies have a 'common stock' between them that is as readily tradable as the noted mutual fund.